# Concatenation of two dataframe after onehotencoding

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let us consider following code

```
import pandas  as pd
import numpy as np
Names =pd.Series(["A","B","C","A","B","B","A","C","C","B","A","C"],name="Alphabet")
Strings =pd.DataFrame(Names)
print(Strings.head(12))
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
MyEncoder=OneHotEncoder(sparse=False)
encoded =MyEncoder.fit_transform(Strings[["Alphabet"]])
print(encoded)
print(MyEncoder.categories_)
Encoded_Dataframe =pd.DataFrame(encoded)
Encoded_Dataframe.columns =list(MyEncoder.categories_)
print(Encoded_Dataframe.head())
Strings =pd.concat([Strings,Encoded_Dataframe],axis=1)
print(Strings.head())
```

result of this code is following ( i am writing final dataframe)

```
 Alphabet  (A,)  (B,)  (C,)
0        A   1.0   0.0   0.0
1        B   0.0   1.0   0.0
2        C   0.0   0.0   1.0
3        A   1.0   0.0   0.0
4        B   0.0   1.0   0.0
```

all others works fine, they are

```
   A    B    C
0  1.0  0.0  0.0
1  0.0  1.0  0.0
2  0.0  0.0  1.0
3  1.0  0.0  0.0
4  0.0  1.0  0.0
```

so my  point is to remove commas in  header part of the final dataframe, please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding:

```
Encoded_Dataframe.columns = [''.join(col) for col in Encoded_Dataframe.columns]
```

Your columns are a multi-index in `Encoded_Dataframe`. If you write: `Encoded_Dataframe.columns`, you will get `MultiIndex([('A',),('B',),('C',)],)` and see what I mean, so you need to change the column names with what I have suggested, by joining the multiple levels with an empty string, so that you have one string as a column name instead of a tuple.

Also, you could use `Strings = Strings.join(Encoded_Dataframe)` as an alternative to `Strings = pd.concat([Strings,Encoded_Dataframe],axis=1)`:

Full Code:

```
import pandas  as pd
import numpy as np
Names =pd.Series(["A","B","C","A","B","B","A","C","C","B","A","C"],name="Alphabet")
Strings =pd.DataFrame(Names)
print(Strings.head(12))
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
MyEncoder=OneHotEncoder(sparse=False)
encoded =MyEncoder.fit_transform(Strings[["Alphabet"]])
print(encoded)
print(MyEncoder.categories_)
Encoded_Dataframe =pd.DataFrame(encoded)
Encoded_Dataframe.columns =list(MyEncoder.categories_)
print(Encoded_Dataframe.head())
Encoded_Dataframe.columns = [''.join(col) for col in Encoded_Dataframe.columns]
Strings =pd.concat([Strings,Encoded_Dataframe],axis=1)
print(Strings.head())
   Alphabet
0         A
1         B
2         C
3         A
4         B
5         B
6         A
7         C
8         C
9         B
10        A
11        C
[[1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1.]
 [1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0.]
 [1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 1. 0.]
 [1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1.]]
[array(['A', 'B', 'C'], dtype=object)]
     A    B    C
0  1.0  0.0  0.0
1  0.0  1.0  0.0
2  0.0  0.0  1.0
3  1.0  0.0  0.0
4  0.0  1.0  0.0
  Alphabet    A    B    C
0        A  1.0  0.0  0.0
1        B  0.0  1.0  0.0
2        C  0.0  0.0  1.0
3        A  1.0  0.0  0.0
4        B  0.0  1.0  0.0
```

Comment: sir  so command ' '.join(col) will remove any other   term right, for instance  comma in this case

Comment: The commas will be removed, because you are joining a Tuple hat is separated by commas.

Comment: for instance following code for col in Encoded_Dataframe.columns:
    print(col)    will print tuples, but ' '.join(col) removes commas interesting, actually tuple is  ('A',)  so anyway   thank you for your efford